# If a RewriteCond is true, does Apache go through the entire htaccess file again starting from the top?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Suppose we have an htaccess file that looks like this.

```
RewriteCond A
RewriteRule 1

RewriteCond B
RewriteRule 2
```

If condition B is found to be true, then RewriteRule number 2 will be executed.

Does that mean Apache will go through the entire htaccess file again, starting from the top?

If it doesn't, then is there some setting that will make it?

Comment: As long as any rewrite occurred, the whole process will be started from the top again, when rewriting is configured in .htaccess context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the Flags, but the basic work flow is like this.

In your example if `RewriteCond A` is matching than that dose not mean `RewriteRule 1` will be applied, because the Rule itself have to match as well.

But if we assume this it the case and `RewriteRule 1` match then it will applied.

Now depending on the Flags it could be that `mod_rewrite` will directly check the next `RewriteCond` / `RewriteRule` group, in your case `RewriteCond B` &
`RewriteRule 2` and apply it as well if all matches.

If any Rule is applied, than `mod_rewite` takes the result and do the hole procedure from the beginning till no rule will applied any more.

The common Flags that will influence this behavior are [[L] Last](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l), [[N] Next](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_n) and [[END]](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end).